# What does operator()() in c++ do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++11 thread , when reading a tutorial , I see a piece of code like this.

```
 #include <thread>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class background_task
 {
  public:
     void operator()() const
     {
         cout<<"This is a new thread";
     }
 };

int main()
{
   background_task f;
   std::thread my_thread(f);
   my_thread.join();
}
```

The output will be "This is new thread", but i don' really understand what does the function "operator()() const" mean?. In this case, it acts really the same with the constructor, is it right?.

And how can C++ have a syntax like that? I have search about related topic by using the search engine but no found no result.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Search for "functor" in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just operator overloading and has nothing to do with C++11 or multi-threading. An overloaded operator is just a normal function with a funny name (this may be a bit oversimplified, but it's a good rule of thumb for beginners).

Your class has a **function named `()`**. That's all. *Technically*, you could as well have named the function `foo` or `f` or `TwoParentheses`.

Consider a simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "()"; }
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo"; }
    void TwoParentheses() { std::cout << "TwoParentheses"; }
};

int main()
{
    Example e;
    e.operator()();
    e.foo();
    e.TwoParentheses();
}
```

Now calling an overloaded operator like in this example in `main`, spelling out the entire `.operator()` part, is pretty pointless, because an overloaded operator's purpose is to make the calling code simpler. You would instead invoke your function like this:

```
int main()
{
    Example e;
    e();
}
```

As you can see, `e();` now looks exactly as if you called a function.

This is why `operator()` is a special name, after all. In a **template**, you can handle objects with `operator()` and function pointers with the **same syntax**.

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
 public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Example.operator()\n"; }
};

void function() { std::cout << "Function\n"; }

template <class Operation>
void t(Operation o)
{
    o(); // operator() or "real" function
}

int main()
{
    Example object;
    t(object);
    t(function);
}
```

This is the reason why `operator()` is an important function in C++ generic programming, and is often required.

Answer (score 7):

`void operator()()` means an instance of the class with that operator can be called with function call syntax, with no return value, and without any parameters. For example:

```
background_task b;

b(); // prints "This is a new thread"
```

The `operator()` part indicates it is a call operator, the second set of empty parentheses `()` indicate the operator has no parameters. Here is an example with two parameters and a return value:

```
struct add
{
  int operator()(int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
};

add a;
int c = a(1, 2); // c initialized to 1+2
```

Note that this syntax pre-dates C++11. You can create callable types (also referred to as *functors*) in C++03. The connection with C++11 is that the `std::thread` constructor expects something that can be called without arguments . This could be a plain function

```
void foo() {}
```

a static member function

```
struct foo {
  static void bar() {}
};
```

an instance of a type such as `background_task`, a suitable *lambda* expression, a suitable invocation of `std::bind`, in short, anything that can be called without arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with C++11, it's the function call overload operator. That means if you have a class like yours, you can create an instance of it and use as a function:

```
int main()
{
    background_task bt;
    bt();
}
```

The above `main` function should give the same result as your simple thread example.

Answer (score 0):

it is operator over loading. the user provide an additional use to () operator. Example for static polymorphism. it is fearture of Object orieted program

Comment: It's not a feature of object-oriented programming at all, at least with the usual definition of object-oriented programming in C++. Object-oriented programming means run-time polymorphism. **OOP = virtual functions.** Operator overloading usually makes sense for classes without any virtual functions, and vice versa.